# Comment styling dependent on author's user roles

Tags: 7, theming, comments, users

I want to style comments differently depending of the author's user roles. How can i add a specific class attribute in the comment template if the author of the comment has a certain role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it myself. Here is how to do it:

In your theme `template.php`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$vars) {
    // user roles
    // 1 = anonymous user
    // 2 = authenticated user
    // 3 = administrator
    // ...
    $vars['role_classes'] = '';
    $sql = "SELECT users_roles.rid FROM {users_roles} WHERE users_roles.uid = " . ((int) $vars['comment']->uid);
    $result = db_query($sql);
    foreach($result as $record) {
        $roleId = $record->rid;
        if($roleId == 3) $vars['role_classes'] .= ' comment-by-admin';
    }
}
```

Then change in your `comment.tpl.php`

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

to

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?><?php print $role_classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to add an extra class to the body tag, so you can target .comment etc. inside the body.role-xxx - you can then use it on any element on the page

The site I'm on right now has

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in no-sidebars page-node page-node- page-node-521317 node-type-article" >
```

You need to add another to that by

```
global $user;
$custom = '';
foreach($user->roles as $key => $value ) {
  $custom .= ' role-' . $key; //or value, if you prefer 
}
// add the string to the body attributes in the link below
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7

Sorry, that is a bit garbled as I've got to run out the door right this second - but hopefully you can decipher and get your answer ;o)

Edit:

Tested working solution for you (I was slightly off with my guess yesterday)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  foreach($user->roles as $key => $value) {
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'role-' . $key;
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
body.role-3 .comment {
  border: 2px solid green
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what i need, because the role is not page related, but comment related. I can have 10 comments on the same page with different authors which should be rendered dependent on the role of the comment author.

Comment: Yeh, sorry I misread the question (thinking you meant 'logged in user'). I would certainly recommend against doing a database query on every comment template preprocess though - that will not scale well at all if you have a lot of authenticated traffic... although I can't think of a proper solution. It might be that performance is not an issue for the type of site you are building? (Sometimes you do just have to wang in a DB query here and there to get Drupal to do what you want)

Comment: You are right, i didn't thought of the performance issues of my solution. Shouldn't be a big problem at the moment, but i'd love to see another and better scaling option.